# Exporting attribute table with 100,000+ features into Excel file using ArcGIS Explorer?

Tags: export, features, excel, arcgis-explorer, files

I need to export the underlying data contained in these GIS files (http://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/firehistory/data.html) into a .txt or .ascii file.

I am using ArcGIS explorer so I do not have the "Table to Excel function."

Some of the layers have less than 100,000 features so I've been creating attribute tables and then exporting those as .txt files. Some of the layers have >100,000 features. I'm at a loss for how to export those into an excel file.

Comment: Have you tried exporting > 100.000 features to Excell? What happened?

Answer (score 6):

If exporting to excel you would have to be within the limitations of the spreadsheet, which is available on Microsoft help [page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

> Worksheet size

1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns

In addition, you can follow these different methods as outlined by ESRI on their support page [here](http://support.esri.com/ES/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/44595)

> Option A: For ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 and above, using the Table to Excel tool:

1. Start ArcMap.
2. Open the Table To Excel tool from ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > Excel > Table To Excel. -show me-
3. Specify the Input Table from the drop-down list, or move the feature class into the text box.
4. Specify the Output Excel File. -show me-
5. Click OK. The Excel file is created in the designated output location.

> Option B: Copy and paste all records in the attribute table into the Excel file:

1. Start ArcMap.
2. Open the attribute table; right-click the feature class > Open Attribute Table. -show me-
3. Click the Table Options arrow > Select All. -show me-
4. Right-click the left-most column of the attribute table, and select Copy Selected. -show me-
5. Start Microsoft Excel.
6. Right-click cell A1 of the Excel file, and select Paste. -show me-
7. Save the file.

> Option C: Export the attribute table to a CSV file:

1. Follow steps 1 and 2 in Option B above.
2. Click the Table Options arrow, and select Export. -show me-
3. Under 'Output table', click folder browsing icon. -show me-
4. Under 'Save as type', click the drop-down list, and select Text File. -show me-
5. Specify the desired name and change the '.txt' to '.csv' to the name.
6. Click Save.
7. Navigate to the folder location through Windows Explorer to view the .csv file in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Another option worth mentioning (if the data is stored in the SDE) is the use of a [SQL connection through excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad). You cannot edit the data directly, but it's fairly easy to copy it out.

Comment: Ah, I've been using ArcGIS explorer so have not seen this option. thank you!